# Spring Boot Actuator not showing any information

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot version **2.2.5.RELEASE** and have trouble to receive any information from the actuator endpoint. What I'm receiving is only the empty structure of Actuator as following:

[image]

This is my configuration:

```java
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
```

```java
@Bean
public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
   return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
}
```

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hallelujah, finally found the issue of my above described problem!

The problem was that i configured my spring boot application to use *Gson* instead of the default *Jackson* json parser. Not completely  clear why, but with the following lines of code it results in issues to show the data at the actuator endpoints.

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-json"
}
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
```

The following above described Bean is also unnecessary!

```
@Bean
public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
   return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
}
```

The following configuration was hence as well a problem:

```
spring:
  http:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
  gson:
    exclude-fields-without-expose-annotation: true
```

And finally with removing of all of my *@Expose* annotations it started to work perfectly fine again.

```
@Expose
private String content;
```

If anyone can explain to me why this happened, or how to configure *Gson* to work properly with *Spring Boot Actuator* in combination, I'm here to listen and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed by removing the following line

```
gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
```